# Trouble with rpi-source (hello world kernel module)

Tags: kernel, modules, rpi-source

the first time I ran rpi-source (https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki) I had no trouble at all getting the hello world kernel module to run.

I deleted the kernel headers, and when I now run rpi-source, it proceeds to ask me hundreds of questions about my kernel config (after headers have been unpacked), which it did not the first time. I don't know what to answer to all those questions. If I keep enter pressed for all questions I cannot compile the hello world code any more:

```
/bin/sh: 1: scripts/mod/modpost: not found
make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 127
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

How can I get back to the behaviour where it generated the config automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel headers are usually installed via the package manager `apt`. If you manually removed them then the package manager will still think you have them installed you need to reinstall.

do `aptitude search linux-header` lines beginning with `i` show install packages.

then `sudo aptitude reinstall linux-header…` probably just `sudo aptitude reinstall linux-header` for the default kernel.

Answer (score 1):

When rpi-source is run and the source is installed, it says so and quits:

```
$ rpi-source
[...]
 *** Kernel source already installed: /home/pi/linux-342abe67d0e1f12eae17562bfe7615143d2618d1

$
```

Deleting this directory, makes rpi-source unpack and prepare the source again:

```
$ rm -rf /home/pi/linux-342abe67d0e1f12eae17562bfe7615143d2618d1
$ rpi-source
[...]
 *** Download kernel source: Already downloaded /home/pi/linux-342abe67d0e1f12eae17562bfe7615143d2618d1.tar.gz

 *** Unpack kernel source
[...]
```